# electron js Speech Recognition network error

Tags: javascript, electron, webspeech-api

I made an app with speech recognition and it worked well for a week or something like that and after time it just stopped working, i compiled the app and sent in to my friends, everyone have same error : 'network', i tried to delete all main code and just have recognition init and of course console logging on result to see what happens and the same error is appearing every second. Can u guys help me with it? code will be bellow. It's working in chrome, but not in electron, i can't find answers on web, maybe u can help me :D

```
const SpeechRecognition =
     window.speechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

recognition.onstart = () => {
    console.log("start of recognition");
};

recognition.onend = function () {
    recognition.continuous = true;
    recognition.start();
    console.log("end of recognition");
};

recognition.onerror = function (event) {
    console.log(`Error occurred in recognition: ${event.error}`);
};

recognition.onresult = (event) => {
    const current = event.resultIndex;
    const transcript = event.results[current][0].transcript;
    console.log(transcript)
};
```